# Laravel log after save() only when changed

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

In my Laravel project, I am trying to add some logging when my Eloquent model has been changed. When the model has not been changed, I do not want to log anything. I only want to log something after it has been saved to the database, to make sure the changes are valid (e.g. if there was an error during the save action and due to an error the changes did not get saved, the log does not make any sense anymore).

My first instinct was to use `->isDirty()` like so:

```
$myModel->save();
if ($myModel->isDirty()) {
    // Do the logging there were changes
}
```

However, this does not work, because the `->isDirty()` method 'resets' when performing a `->save()`. Just like the `->getDirty()` for that matter.

As an alternative I looked into the working of `$model->save()`, as that will return a boolean on whether it saved or not. However, even if a query (to change the model) wasn't performed it will still return true since technically it didn't fail.

My current solution is something like this:

```
$hasMyModelBeenChanged = $myModel->isDirty();

$myModel->save();
if ($hasMyModelBeenChanged) {
    // Do the logging there were changes
}
```

I assume this use-case must be very common thus some recommendation or fluent implementation must exist, rendering the above fix suboptimal. My question is if there exists an Eloquent method that I have missed just like `->isDirty()` so signify a changed model that returns true even after the model has been saved to the database. Or maybe the recommendation is that I should look into transactions in this situation?

Comment: I don't really see what's wrong with the current solution? What exactly is wrong with it? I don't see how you can get away without an `if`-statement, and the rest is just one single line?

Comment: @M.Eriksson You might be right, but I was just expecting there was a more fluent way to get this done. I would argue a shorter and more elegant method for this would fit into the Laravel/Eloquent philosophy. I would accept your answer if no other method exists.

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent#observers

Comment: check out this [library](https://spatie.be/docs/laravel-activitylog/v4/advanced-usage/logging-model-events)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As stated by [the Laravel docs](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent?:text:#method:%7E:text=The-,wasChanged,-method%20determines%20if), you can use the `wasChanged` method. This method determines if any attributes were changed when the model was last saved within the current request cycle. If needed, you may pass an attribute name to see if a particular attribute was changed.

This means that for the question we need to do:

```
$myModel->save();
if ($myModel->wasChanged()) {
    // Do the logging there were changes
}
```